# Profile page links to random answer for my awarded "Great Answer" badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, profile-page

As we can see here I was recently awarded a "Great Answer" badge on my [politics.SE profile](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/13484/sleepinggod),
[image: Strange badge?]

Which is great and all **except** for the fact I never answered the question I have been "Awarded [it] for". Indeed when I click on the link it take me to [this answer.](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-is-meant-by-the-left-and-the-right/13#13)Which is answer by one [Sven Clement](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/18/sven-clement), now this has two problems

1. **I am not Sven Clement**, I am SleepingGod - I should not be awarded badges for another persons answer
2. No disrespect intended to Mr Clement but his answer (at this time of writing) has only got 68 Public Votes (70 upvotes and 2 downvotes) which means as indicated by this post in the help center that it falls some **32 votes shy of getting a "Great Answer" badge in the first place**. 
   [image: Votes needed for a badge]

Now I do deserve a "Great Answer" badge in the first place for my answer [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/19183/13484), this is simply a bug report that the pop-up box when I click on it in my profile leads to an unerringly random answer that has **nothing to do with me** and wasn't supposed to **get such a badge in the first place**.

**The bug is reproducible, I have tested it on 3 different browsers**

<s>You can test this bug out yourself by going on my "[Activity Page](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/13484/sleepinggod?tab=topactivity)", and clicking on my "Newest" badge.</s> This is no longer possible because I earnt a new badge in the meantime, however this is still a technical glitch that needs looking into.

Comment: That is strange. By the way, the correct answer *is* displayed on [this page](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/great-answer?userid=13484) (accessible by clicking the badge in the main badge list at the bottom of the profile page). I can confirm that the pop-up link on the activity tab is incorrect, though, I see the same thing you do on your profile.

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour too. Really strange indeed ^^

Comment: Confirmed this is a bug - looking into it now.

Comment: @SleepingGod could you confirm that [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/great-answer?userid=13484) is the one that you believe *should* have been correctly awarded?

Comment: @JonChan yes I can confirm that

Comment: @JonChan: "status-planned" means near-term, but that was 4 years ago.  Any update? [Here is another report today.](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8556/medal-bug-linking-to-wrong-question)

Comment: @toolic Hey, thanks for raising this. I'm bumping this again with the team to look into a fix for the more recent report and will revisit this report as part of it.

Answer (score 6):

This has now been fixed.

There was a logic error in the sql that was used to retrieve the "last post used to earn a specific badge for a specific user" that often resulted in returning a completely unrelated post. The issue would manifest itself specifically when the user had earned another badge of specific types more recently than the badge was earned connected to the post.

---

> go and earn a badge
> related to post actions
> link to post now fixed